# Creating a gradebook program in C

Tags: c

I'm working on a program that will keep track of grades entered.  The program should ask if the user is finished inputting grades.  If the the user is not finished, the user will continue to enter grades.  If the user is finished, program will print the grades.  Every time I run the program, it crashes.

Here's what I got.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int i = 0;
    float gradeBook;
    char ans, y, Y, n, N;

    printf("Please enter grade %d: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%.2f", &gradeBook);

    printf("\nDo you have more grades to enter? [Y or N] ");
    scanf("%c", ans);

    while(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y'){
        printf("Please enter the next grade %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%i", &gradeBook);

        printf("\nDo you have more grades to enter? ");
        scanf("%c", ans);
    }
    printf("You have entered %d grades", i);
    printf("The grades you have entered are %.2f ", gradeBook);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to run this under your debugger, but note: 'scanf("%c", ans);' needs a '&'.

Comment: Really, you should not attempt programs of this complexity, (that means 'more complex than 'Hello world'), without knowing how to use your debugger effectively.  You should at least be able to tell us which line caused the crash.

Comment: How do you expect a single variable `gradeBook` hold multiple values? what are the variables `y`, `Y`, `n`, `N` for?

Comment: enable compiler warnings, eg with `gcc`, compile with `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: Also, this 'Every time I run the program, it crashes.' is not helpful.  If you tell us how far it gets before crashing, it would be at least a slightly better question.

Comment: @Felix Thank you.  I'm taking an online programming course.  I'm pretty much on my own learning this stuff.  This stuff doesn't come naturally to me.  All of the gcc -std=c11...  Is Greek to me, and I've taken two years of Greek.  Is there a place I can learn about that which kinda breaks it down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use arrays for problems like this. Here is what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
int i = 0, j;
float gradeBook[20];
char ans;

printf("Please enter grade %d: ", i + 1);
scanf("%f", &gradeBook[0]);

printf("\nDo you have more grades to enter? [Y or N] \n");
scanf(" %c", &ans);

while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y') {
printf("Please enter the next grade: \n");
i += 1;
scanf("%f", &gradeBook[i]);

printf("\nDo you have more grades to enter? \n");
scanf(" %c", &ans);
}

printf("You have entered %d grades\n", i+1);
printf("The grades you have entered are: \n");
for (j=0; j<=i; j++)
printf("%.2f ", gradeBook[j]);

printf("\n\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: Thank you for your help evandro10!  I got it to work with some modifications.  Now is there a way that I can get an answer that reads: 

Grade 1 is 88
Grade 2 is 99
Grade 3 is 78

and so on.

Comment: of course, just edit the last for loop, delete the line before that says:
     printf("The grades you have entered are: \n");
and put this inside:
    for (j=0; j<=i; j++)
    printf("Grade %d is %.2f \n", j+1, gradeBook[j]);

Answer (score 1):

Your program crashes because you are missing the & in ans in your scanf. Without the &, the scanf treats the value in "ans" as an address, and will try to access it, thus seg fault.

PS: In each iteration you are overwriting the value in "gradeBook", if you want to print a set of values, you should use an array.